# QGIS Create thermal map from sampled points

Tags: qgis

I have a layer with several thousand points containing data for average yearly temperature. I would like to turn this data into a raster map. What is the best way to do this? Rendering the points as a heatmap isn't what I'm after. I'm trying to get a visual display of the average temperatures in a given area.

Comment: Do you want to do interpolation? In other words, do you also want to show the temperature in places where you *dont* have points? Or do you want to divide your area into squares and show the average temp of points in each square, leaving squares with no points in as blank?

Comment: @Spacedman Yes, the idea is to get data everywhere, not just at the points. It doesn't have to be perfect. This is for fantasy cartography.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for interpolation. There are different methods and formulae for this. This is a tutorial on interpolation: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/interpolating_point_data.html#interpolating-point-data-qgis3

See the note after step 9 for some info on the different methods.